# Strings and Arrays in C language

Tags: arrays, c, string, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() 
{ 
    printf("%d", "123456"[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

The expected output is 123456, but it actually outputs 50. Why is that?

Comment: Try `printf ("%d", 123456);` without the quotes and the [1] instead...

Comment: I always wonder what the use is of explaining bad code.

Comment: @Cheatah "*I always wonder what the use is of explaining bad code*" Maybe you still don't understand that this site is also for beginners? Everyone makes more or less bad code, and beginners more than others. Sometimes they're lost and post here, to learn. Sure their code sucks, they still have a lot to comprehend. And sometimes they're received by downvoters like you who forgot they used to be beginners.

Comment: Of course I understand this site is also for beginners. I just think it's a bad idea to show beginners weird fringe cases of ridiculous code. I don't think OP came up with this code, they were given it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`"123456"[1]` gives the character `'2'`. That character's ascii value is `50`.

To print the full number do: `printf ("%d", 123456);` or `printf ("%s", "123456");`

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to print an integer using `%d` but you have provided a char instead. To get your expected output, either you have to provide an integer as 2nd argument to printf or use `%s` as format specifier.

`printf ("%d", 123456);` or `printf ("%s", "123456");`

Now, explanation about the output `50` you are getting:

Here, "123456" is a `const char *`, so when you tried to fetch value from a particular index using `[1]`, it takes the index `1` of your `const char *` which is **char** `2`.

> index -> 0 1 2 3 4 5
>
> input -> 1 2 3 4 5 6

Now, as you were printing using format specifier `%d` (integer), it printed the ASCII value of **char** `2`, which is `50`.

Answer (score 4):

If you need the exact string then there's no need of format specifiers
you can simply do

```
printf("123456");
```

You are getting output as 50 because in C String are considered as array of char and it can typecast values according to format specifiers too.

So here "123456" becomes an array.
char at 1 index is 2.
and integer value of char "2" i.e ascii value of 2 is 50.
Hence the output.